# Strange mistake when calculate improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I want to calculate the following improper integral, so I do:
$$
\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}} \cos^{2/3} x \sin^{-2/3} x\,dx = 
\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}} \frac{\cos x \cos^ {2/3} x}{\cos x \sin^{2/3}x}\,dx = 
\int_0^{{\pi}/{2}}\frac{3\cos^{2/3} x\,d(\sin^{1/3} x)}{\cos x} =$$
$$\int_0^1\frac{3\,dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = 3\arcsin t |_0^1 = \frac{3\pi}{2}
$$

However, when I evalute it numerically in MatLab, it shows the answer about $\pi$. It seems that there is a problem at discontinuity point $x = 0$, but I don't understand why, because I could use limits and get the same result.

Comment: If $t = \sin^{1/3} x$, then $\cos^{1/3} x = \sqrt[6]{1-t^6}$ (since everything here is non-negative).

Comment: Oh, crap.. Such a mistake.. Does there exist a better substitution?

Comment: Do you happen to know the Beta function?

Comment: No, I don't. Is it the only way to calculate this integral?

Comment: There's always more than one way [almost always?]. It's just very easy if you know the Beta function, since that directly gives you $\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{5}{6}\right)$.

Comment: For $|a|<1$ we have $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\cot^ax~dx=\frac\pi2\sec\bigg(k\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$.

Comment: How did you get such a result? And what is k parameter?

Comment: I believe the $k$ is a typo and should really be an '$a$'. Right @Lucian ?

Comment: @perlik Would you mind telling us a little bit about your level of math education? That information would help us avoid answers that are above your abilities.

Comment: @perlik: By using the [Wallis integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals) expression for the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), and then employing Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). And yes, $a=k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method of calculation is conceivably the most elementary, though it has the disadvantage of being a good bit longer than more advanced methods (e.g., via the beta function).

Substituting first $t=\cot{(x)}$ followed by $u=t^{\frac13}$, and then expanding by partial fractions, yields:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cot^{\frac23}{(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{\frac23}}{t^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{3u^4}{u^6+1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{u^2+1}+\frac{2u^2-1}{u^4-u^2+1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+1}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2u^2-1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u.\\
\end{align}$$

The second integral in the last line above may be reduced from an integral over $[0,\infty)$ to an integral over $[0,1]$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2u^2-1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2u^2-1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2u^2-1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2u^2-1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2-w^2}{w^4-w^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}w;~\left(\text{from }u\rightarrow\frac{1}{w}\right)\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2u^2-1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2-u^2}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^2+1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u.\\
\end{align}$$

We can show via substitution that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^2+1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+1}$. To demonstrate this, we can start from the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+1}$ and substitute $\frac{u}{1-u^2}$:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+1}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{u}{1-u^2}\right)^2+1}\cdot\frac{u^2+1}{\left(1-u^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^2+1}{u^2+\left(1-u^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^2+1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u.\\
\end{align}$$

Putting this all together, we get:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cot^{\frac23}{(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+1}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2u^2-1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+1}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^2+1}{u^4-u^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+1}+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+1}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+1}\\
&=2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\overbrace{\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2/3}\pars{x}\sin^{-2/3}\pars{x}\,\dd x}}
^{\dsc{\sin\pars{x}=t\ \imp\ x=\arcsin\pars{x}}}\ =\
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t^{2}}^{1/3}t^{-2/3}\,{\dd t \over \pars{1 - t^{2}}^{1/2}}
\\[5mm]&=\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}t^{-2/3}\pars{1 - t^{2}}^{-1/6}\,\dd t}
^{\dsc{t^{2}\ \mapsto\ t}}\ =\
\int_{0}^{1}t^{-1/3}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/6}\,\half\,t^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{1}t^{-5/6}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/6}\,\dd t
=\half\,{\Gamma\pars{1/6}\Gamma\pars{5/6} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}
=\half\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi/6}}=\half\,{\pi \over 1/2}
=\color{#66f}{\Large\pi}
\end{align}